# Expo 404 on webbuild

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, expo

I try to compile an expo web app, but after the compilation with "expo build:web" ends, when I open the project with "npx serve web-build", the web browser displays this screen :

[image]

I tried to solve this configuring the wepack.config.js and enabling offline mode but it did not solve anything.

```js
//My webpack.config.js

const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require("@expo/webpack-config");

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(
    {
      ...env,
      // Passing true will enable the default Workbox + Expo SW configuration.
      offline: true,
    },
    argv
  );
  // Customize the config before returning it.
  return config;
};
```

my app.json :

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "maqueta",
    "slug": "maqueta",
    "platforms": ["web"],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `-s`

```
npx serve -s web-build
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the -s flag does? Also can it be applied to production builds?